# Linear independence of $(a,a^2,a^3)$, $(b,b^2,b^3)$, $(c,c^2,c^3)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show that the set of all $(a,a^2,a^3)$, $a\in\mathbb{R}\neq 0$ is a subset in  $\mathbb{R^3}$ where every $3$-subset$ is linear independent.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If they were linearly dependent, there would be a quadratic equation with roots $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: If you want to find out more information about this, I recommend you to look for Vandermonde matrix. Here you have the wiki if you want it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $a\neq b\neq c \neq 0$ and compute the determinant of
$$
A=\pmatrix{a&b&c\\ a^2& b^2 & c^2 \\ a^3 & b^3 & c^3}
$$
When you compute the determinant, you can threat $A$ as a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). Hence the determinant is 
$$
\text{det}A = abc (c-a)(c-b)(b-a)
$$
and thanks to the hypotesis, $\text{A}\neq 0$ and $A$ is invertible. Hence the three vectors are linearly independent.

---

In order to use the definition, we want to show that
$$
\pmatrix{a\\a^2\\a^3}x + \pmatrix{b\\b^2\\b^3}y + \pmatrix{c\\c^2\\c^3}z =0 
$$
implies $x=y=z=0$. The condition is equivalent to the following system:
\begin{gather}
\begin{cases}
ax+by+cz = 0\\
a^2x+b^2y+c^2z = 0\\
a^3x+b^3y+c^3z = 0
\end{cases}
\end{gather}
This is equivalent (multiply first row by $a$ and subtract to second; multiply second row by $a$ and subtract to third, we can do these operations because $a,b,c\neq 0$):
\begin{gather}
\begin{cases}
ax+by+cz = 0\\
b(a-b)y = c(c-a)z\\
b^2(a-b)y = c^2(c-a)z
\end{cases}
\end{gather}
And mulipling by $b$ the second row and subtract to third we obtain:
$$
c(c-a)(b-a)z = 0
$$
Since $a\neq c, b\neq a, c\neq 0$ we have $z=0$. Hence $y=0$ by the second row of the second system and $x=0$ by the first row of the first system.

Comment: can I show it somehow without using determinants?

Comment: Use elementary row operations to show that the matrix has rank $3$.

Comment: Yes you can. Solve the system Ax=0 and use a non trivial solution.

Comment: @New2Math I Edited my post with a solution. Tell me if it is ok for you :)

Comment: @menezio thank you it is perfect